# Base class pointer for a template class that uses template parameter in member data

Tags: c++, template-classes

For the following template class

```
template <class T> class Arbitrary {
protected:
    vector<T> ObjectArray;
public:
    Arbitrary(){}   
};
```

I want to be able to have a vector of base class pointers, I know I need to use an interface class but I can't get it to work, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"can't get it to work"*? What exactly have you tried doing, what is happening, what errors are you getting, ...

Comment: I have no idea what to do,  I know I want to eventually write vector<Arbitrary*> name;

Comment: That can't really work since `Arbitrary` is a template type, so you can only do something like `vector<Arbitrary<int>*> name;` - or use something like `std::any` or `std::variant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [..] I want to eventually write `vector<Arbitrary*> name;`

`Arbitrary` is a template, not a type. To "obtain" a type from it, you need to "apply" it to another type (like `int`). This gives you `Arbitrary<int>` as "result" type. This process is called *template instantiation*.

If you want a vector with objects of any possible type that might have been instantiated from the template `Arbitrary`, then you need to give them a common type (such that every object "is a" object of that common type). This is because `std::vector` stores only objects of a single type.

To have the objects "behave" (in the sense of having some type) differently even though they "have" a common type, you need to make them (or rather their common type) *polymorphic*. This is done by giving the common type some `virtual` function. (And since you want to delete/destruct objects through the "interface" exposed by the common type you **need** to make the destructor virtual!)

```
struct ArbitraryBase {
  // Add "common interface" functions here, as virtual
  virtual ~ArbitraryBase() = 0; // pure virtual to avoid creating objects
};
inline ArbitraryBase​::~ArbitraryBase() {}

template<typename T>
struct Arbitrary : ArbitraryBase {
  // whatever
};
```

Now, to actually be able to use that polymorphic property and not become victim of *object slicing* you need to use reference or pointer semantics:

```
std::vector<ArbitraryBase *> objects;
```

Instead of raw pointers you should consider smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<ArbitraryBase>` if the `objects` vector should have ownership of the objects or otherwise use `std::reference_wrapper<ArbitraryBase>` in case lifetime of the objects is *reliably* handled by something else.

But if you don't add any common interface (more virtual member functions) in `ArbitraryBase` then you're basically reinventing `std::any` / `boost::any`. So better use those well tested implementations instead.

Comment: Thanks, i am using more virtual member functions. How do I deal with virtual member functions that are functions of T i.e virtual void function(T)

Comment: You cannot have such member functions. `T` is nothing which is "common" to all types instantiated from `Arbitrary`. Actually - assuming no template specialisations - `T` is what's different for all those types.